# In Jinjia2, how to use a variable value in html style?

Tags: css, html, jinja2, templating

I would like to place a small image at different position based on a variable value - for example, say I have a `v_position` variable, if its value is 50, the image will be in the horizontal center, and if its value is 100, the image will be on the right most place on the page.

Here's the line that I insert the image:

```
<img src="image.png" style="position: relative; left: {{ v_position% }};">
```

The page still get rendered but the position of this `image.png` is not changing with different `v_position` values. How could I make it work as I expected? Thanks!

Comment: that syntax is not correct. To achieve something like that you should use a script. Simple HTML and Css don't allow you to work with variable. You could use SCSS as well. What's the final result you want to get? Why you want the image to change position?

Comment: @Blank， the final result I want to get is a batch of pdf files based on a same template - I am generating them for different clients, so I want each pdf be customized (having this image at a different place in this case)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to position the image to the left using a jinja2 variabe, you should also add px or something else like this:

```
<img src="image.png" style="position: relative; left: {{ v_position }}px;">
```

Now your image will placed properly.
The `template_vars["v_position"]=100`returns only 100, that's not enough for the style by itself.

Comment: thanks! Before I saw your answer, I tried adding the unit but left a space before the `px`, and that didn't work. Without the space, it works!

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra `%` character in your Jinja2 expression. Make it `{{ v_position }}` instead.

Comment: I removed the `%` and it does not solve the issue. I suspect the v_position is treated as a string rather than a number in Jinja2?

Comment: Both strings and numbers would be rendered as strings, and it's up to the JavaScript compiler to interpret a token as a number. How are you passing a value for `v_position` to the template renderer?

Comment: I use a `template_var` which is a dictionary in Python, and it includes on key-value pair like `template_vars["v_position"]=100`. Then I do `template.render(template_vars)`. I can properly "print" out other variable values on the pdf as they are. Just not sure how to use this one in the `style`.